# Как настроить 301-редирект для картинок с одного домена на другой?

Tags: wordpress, редирект, изображения

Необходимо в .htaccess настроить 301-редирект для картинок с одного домена на другой. CMS WordPress.

Какой код добавить в .htaccess, чтобы был редирект картинок?

**Сейчас просто редирект домена  и внутренних ссылок настроен:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.net/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.net/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: а в чём, собственно, вопрос? сформулируйте его, пожалуйста, нажав [edit].

Comment: отредактировал. Сейчас просто настроен 301-редирект для домена и внутренних ссылок, а сами картинки не редиректит. Что необходимо добавить в текущий КОД, чтобы их редиректило?

Comment: если не редиректит статику - наверняка на фронте стоит nginx. Он не понимает htacess. А в htacess-е внутри блока ВП делать ничего не нужно - ВП перепишет этот блок. Все свои ридиректы пиши выше.

Comment: Работает как модуль Apache.